# How to pass data from an Activity to a Service normally or with EventBus?

Tags: java, android, string, event-bus

I need to pass a String to a Service that runs in the background, this service gives notifications. I have seen many tutorials but I do not know how to do it.

I've tried using GreenRobot EventBus and Otto Square EventBus

Tried this but it did not work:

This is the activity I want to pass the string
(Code relevant)

And in this, I am using Otto EventBus

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 mButtonsetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         BusStation.getBus().post(new Mensaje("Hello world"));             

        }
    });
```

The model classes:
//========================================

```
     public class BusStation {
private static Bus bus = new Bus();

public static Bus getBus() {
    return bus;
}
}
```

Data pass:

```
 public class Mensaje {
private String msg;

public Mensaje(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}
 }
```

//========================================
The BackGroundService:

```
      public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends Service {






@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

  BusStation.getBus().register(this);
 }
 }  

  @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    BusStation.getBus().unregister(this);
} 



 @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe
public void receiveMessage(Mensaje mensaje){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensaje.getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

But I don't get anything in the Toast, I've also tried using Log.d.

Comment: Otto has been discontinued. You are better served using another event bus implementation (greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, etc.). Note that your service will only receive messages when it is running and if it is in the same process as the activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare In the same process as the activity? The Service runs since the app starts, so if it works?

Comment: "The Service runs since the app starts" -- only if something starts it. Services do not start themselves.

Comment: @CommonsWare In the part of the manifest there is a ..App, there start the service and from there it runs in the background until it goes out, and it is run again when it is turned on by using on BroadcastReceiver, the question is if I can with event bus Get the String? When the Click user?

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create bound service and call service methods directly. Without event bus libraries.
This is how you can do this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder